# Create AD Users from Excel

Tags: excel, powershell, active-directory

I am trying to achieve this with PowerShell script and hope someone can help me with this.

I have an excel sheet containing Column 1 (First Name), Column 2 (Last Name), Column 3 (Location is OU in AD), Column 4 (Role is Job Title in AD).

```
FirstName   LastName   Location(OU)    Role(JobTitle)
Andrew      Smiles      Perth           ISS
```

In Active Directory I have an "UnUsed" OU containing users e.g: 510700, 510701, 510702, to 519960. These are login names and usually are set as disabled until assigned.

Now the action part:

1. Read the excel and combine Column 1 & Column 2, then check in AD if this user exists (Check if matches with the Display Name not the SamAccountName. Read (2.1)) against the Location OU (provided in Column 3).
   Recursive search for the user in other OUs throughout the AD is not required.
2. If the above is OK then pick up the smallest available number from "UnUsed" OU for example in this case it will be 510700.

   1. Change the First Name, Last Name, Job Title of this user 510700 but the Login Name remains the same as 510700 (User is in “UnUsed” OU).
   2. Change the Display Name as in this case would become “Andrew Smiles (510700)”
   3. Now move this user 510700 to the OU provided in Column 3 (Location OU) and enable the account.
   4. Write a log report for all the above procedure.

---------Thanks for the attention I am able to solve it all by myself-----Here is the code incase if someone is interested-----------

```
$file = "C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx"
$sheetName = "Sheet1"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
$rowFName,$colFName = 1,1
$rowLName,$colLName = 1,3
$rowLocation,$colLocation = 1,6
$rowRole,$colRole = 1,7
$rowTotal = $rowMax-1
Write-Output ("Total Number of Records in the EXCEL Sheet are: "+$rowTotal ) >> "C:\Temp\Output.txt"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Unused Users,OU=MYOU,DC=MYDC,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM,DC=au" -server MYAD -ResultSetSize 10000 | 
Select-Object Name | Sort Name | Out-File C:\Temp\UnUsedUsersList.txt
$content = Get-Content C:\Temp\UnUsedUsersList.txt
$content | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content C:\Temp\UnUsedUsersList.txt
[int]$Skip = 3
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{
$FName = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowFName+$i,$colFName).text              #Get first Column i.e First Name
$LName = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowLName+$i,$colLName).text              #Get 3rd Column i.e Last Name
$Name = "$FName "+$LName                                       #Combine the 2 Columns to complete Full Name
$OULocation = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowLocation+$i,$colLocation).text   #Get OU Column of the user
$Role = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowRole+$i,$colRole).text                 #Get Title Column
$UserID = Get-Content "C:\Temp\UnUsedUsersList.txt" | select -skip $Skip | select -First 1
Write-Output ("User Account: " +$Name + " in OU: " +$OULocation + " will be assigned to: " +$UserID + " having Title as: " +$Role ) >> "C:\Temp\Output.txt"

$ADObject = Get-ADUser -Filter {(givenname -eq $FName) -and (sn -eq $LName)} -SearchBase "OU=$OULocation,OU=MYOU,DC=MYDC,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM,DC=au" -server MYAD -ResultSetSize 10000  
    if ($ADObject)
    {
       Write-Output ($Name + " EXIST in OU: " +$OULocation) >> "C:\Temp\Output.txt"
    }
    else 
    {
       $DisplayName = "$Name ($UserID)" 
       Write-Output ($Name + " DOES NOT exist in OU: " +$OULocation) >> "C:\Temp\Output.txt"
Get-ADUser $UserID | Set-ADAccountPassword $UserID -reset -newpassword (ConvertTo-SecureString 'welcome01' -AsPlainText -Force) | 
Set-ADUser -Replace @{GivenName="$FName";DisplayName="$DisplayName";SN="$LName";} -Title $Role -PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName $OULocation -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true |
Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=$OULocation,OU=MYOU,DC=MYDC,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM,DC=au" -server MYAD
     }
       $Skip++
}
$objExcel.quit()
```

Comment: This is not a code-writing service. Try writing the script yourself, come back if you get stuck on a *specific* problem.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include these details - comments are not great for posting code.

Answer (score 0):

---------Thanks for the attention I am able to solve it all by myself-----Here is the code incase if someone is interested-----------

```
$file = "C:\Temp\Book1.xlsx"
$sheetName = "Sheet1"
$objExcel = New-Object -ComObject Excel.Application
$workbook = $objExcel.Workbooks.Open($file)
$sheet = $workbook.Worksheets.Item($sheetName)
$objExcel.Visible=$false
$rowMax = ($sheet.UsedRange.Rows).count
$rowFName,$colFName = 1,1
$rowLName,$colLName = 1,3
$rowLocation,$colLocation = 1,6
$rowRole,$colRole = 1,7
$rowTotal = $rowMax-1
Write-Output ("Total Number of Records in the EXCEL Sheet are: "+$rowTotal ) >> "C:\Temp\Output.txt"
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Unused Users,OU=MYOU,DC=MYDC,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM,DC=au" -server MYAD -ResultSetSize 10000 | 
Select-Object Name | Sort Name | Out-File C:\Temp\UnUsedUsersList.txt
$content = Get-Content C:\Temp\UnUsedUsersList.txt
$content | Foreach {$_.TrimEnd()} | Set-Content C:\Temp\UnUsedUsersList.txt
[int]$Skip = 3
for ($i=1; $i -le $rowMax-1; $i++)
{
$FName = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowFName+$i,$colFName).text              #Get first Column i.e First Name
$LName = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowLName+$i,$colLName).text              #Get 3rd Column i.e Last Name
$Name = "$FName "+$LName                                       #Combine the 2 Columns to complete Full Name
$OULocation = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowLocation+$i,$colLocation).text   #Get OU Column of the user
$Role = $sheet.Cells.Item($rowRole+$i,$colRole).text                 #Get Title Column
$UserID = Get-Content "C:\Temp\UnUsedUsersList.txt" | select -skip $Skip | select -First 1
Write-Output ("User Account: " +$Name + " in OU: " +$OULocation + " will be assigned to: " +$UserID + " having Title as: " +$Role ) >> "C:\Temp\Output.txt"

$ADObject = Get-ADUser -Filter {(givenname -eq $FName) -and (sn -eq $LName)} -SearchBase "OU=$OULocation,OU=MYOU,DC=MYDC,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM,DC=au" -server MYAD -ResultSetSize 10000  
    if ($ADObject)
    {
       Write-Output ($Name + " EXIST in OU: " +$OULocation) >> "C:\Temp\Output.txt"
    }
    else 
    {
       $DisplayName = "$Name ($UserID)" 
       Write-Output ($Name + " DOES NOT exist in OU: " +$OULocation) >> "C:\Temp\Output.txt"
Get-ADUser $UserID | Set-ADAccountPassword $UserID -reset -newpassword (ConvertTo-SecureString 'welcome01' -AsPlainText -Force) | 
Set-ADUser -Replace @{GivenName="$FName";DisplayName="$DisplayName";SN="$LName";} -Title $Role -PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName $OULocation -ChangePasswordAtLogon $true -Enabled $true |
Move-ADObject -TargetPath "OU=$OULocation,OU=MYOU,DC=MYDC,DC=MYDOMAIN,DC=COM,DC=au" -server MYAD
     }
       $Skip++
}
$objExcel.quit()
```